# saving room database data locally

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am using room database in my android app and I want to use it offline to access it from any device that installs the app...
where is the place  I should put my database file in the android application to access it offline?

Comment: Put it in to device internal storage document directory.

Comment: ok Mr Anas but how other devices will access it?

Comment: please, how I can do it Mr  Anas Mehar ?

Comment: Your room database used by only your app or other apps use it to?

Comment: Just my app Mr  Anas Mehar